# US Citizen splitting time between UK and Switzerland

Tags: united-kingdom, schengen, switzerland

Could a US citizen with a UK Long Term Family visa alternate 90 day periods in the UK and Switzerland indefinitely?  Switzerland is a Schengen country, but the UK isn't.

Background: my mother in law is ready to retire.  We live in Switzerland, her other daughter is in the UK.  Our thought: she could spend 90 days here, 90 to 180 in the UK, then 90 here, or even alternate months.

Related: is there a Swiss equivalent to the Long Term Family visa that would simplify the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no rule in the corpus of UK immigration law that requires a given interval between visits, and no rule that restricts the number of visits a person can make.

Yes, as long as any of your visits to the UK are less than 6 months in duration, you can alternate back and forth for as long as your UK visa is valid *AND* at the beginning of each visit, you have a successful landing interview.

Your landing interview will cover [Paragraph 41 of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/381797/Immigration_Rules_-_Part_2_final.pdf), and in your case a special focus on sub-paragraph (ii).

Note: there is a lot of old internet lore on forums from an earlier era describing a 6-month-out-of-12 rule.  Ignore it, Paragraph 41 is the sole controlling reference for family visitors.

## Update 6 July 2015

Paragraph 41 of the rules was abolished last April, the links point to an archived copy.  The current visitor rules are at [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).